# How to connect with Crashlytics with android app

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

[image: Issue is here]

I'm trying to connect with firebase crashltics and integrated as per document. But I'm not able to track issue in firebase and firebase continuously show is following error

Comment: Did you send some exception after intergrating crashlitics in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few Dependencies that you should put in PROJECT & MODULE Gradle.
you can find them in the [Crashlytic's Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) as you sent the picture (**View The Docs**).

> Project's Dependencies:

```
repositories {
...
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
classpath('com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }
}
```

> Module's Dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.5'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
        implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    }
```

**It's IMPORTANT to know**, these dependencies may different in the future. So you can find all of the required in [Crashlytic's Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: These code samples are a little out of date. The firebase docs are very good - best to look there https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

Comment: i'm following the same doc and no issue with integration and app was running perfectly but in firebase it is sowing like "Add the SDK, then build and run your app
View the SDK docs. We’ll be listening for your app to communicate with our servers."

Comment: @enyciaa as you see, I already said and provide refrence to Crashlytic's doc.

Comment: @narayananeduri try manually forcing a crash. So something like throw RuntimeException in onCreate. Then firebase should update.

Comment: @enyciaa Even I have done that. Its still not updating

Answer (score 0):

import
https://github.com/alirezanasrollahzadeh2003/AnCrashLytics

Custom CrashLytics

without Use FireBase